# добавить букву ко всем столбцам в тхт

Tags: c#

Есть тхт в котором есть строки одинаковой длинны то есть 3 бита в каждой из строк, и через пробел снова 3 бита и так 10 раз, как пример показал 2 столбца а таких 10 штук

```
xxx xxx
xxx xxx
xxx xxx
```

чтобы было понятнее
как мне сделать в первом столбце.replace("x","новая буква"); и тоже самое сделать со втором столбцом первой буквой во всех строках первый знак кароче говоря? И сохранить изменения туда же

Comment: А почему работать с неудобными строками, а не десериализвать файл в объектную структуру, поменять, и снова сериализовать? Всё станет гораздо легче.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так:

```
var txt = "xxx xxx\r\nxxx xxx\r\nxxx xxx";
var lines = txt.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// заменить первую
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(0, 1).Insert(0, "y");
}

// заменить первую в следующем слове
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(4, 1).Insert(4, "y");
}

var result = string.Join("\r\n",  lines);
```

Принцип простой. Разбиваете файл по строкам, а дальше берёте первую строку и ищете нужную позицию искомого символа. Потом перебирая все строки удаляете старый символ и по этой позиции вставляете новый.

Вот ещё пример на замену первого символа в каждом столбце каждой строки:

```
var txt = "xxx xxx xxx\r\nxxx xxx xxx\r\nxxx xxx xxx";
var lines = txt.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var columns = lines[i].Split(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j < columns.Length; j++)
    {
        columns[j] = columns[j].Remove(0, 1).Insert(0, "y");
    }

    lines[i] = string.Join(" ", columns);
}

var result = string.Join("\r\n", lines);
```

Comment: А что, в c# нельзя сделать что-то вроде `text[n] = 'Z'` ?

Comment: в c# строковые объекты являются неизменяемыми, по индексу прочитать можно, а поменять нет. Можно получить из строки массив символов, сделать нужные манипуляции и потом создать новую строку.

var chars = columns[j].ToCharArray();
chars[0] = 'y';
columns[j] = new string(chars);

Comment: интересно, как это сказывается на производительности, когда для замены одного символа надо делать Remove/Insert (то есть, по сути, два раза скопировать всю строку)?..

Comment: c# очень хитро работает со строками и поэтому нужно профилировать. Если операций со строками много то лучше воспользоваться StringBuilder и читая из исходной строки сразу менять и писать в StringBuilder. Под капотом он создаёт буфер и при необходимости его расширяет.

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос состоит в том, как заменить первый символ в каждой строке, воспользуйтесь методом [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) в цикле перебора строк.

Пример кода нет смысла выкладывать, Вы должны сами научиться использовать этот простой метод.

**Update:**

```
        private void Check()
        {
            var result = "";
            var ch = 'a';

            var list = new List<string>()
            {
                "xxx xxx",
                "xxx xxx",
                "xxx xxx"
            };

            foreach (var line in list)
                result += ReplaceFirstChar(line, ch) + "\r\n";

            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }

        private string ReplaceFirstChar(string str, char ch)
        {
            var result = "";
            foreach (var line in str.Split(' '))
                result += ch + line.Substring(1, line.Length - 1) + ' ';
            return result.Trim();
        }
```

проверяйте.

Comment: да знаю как код писать, проблема не в этом, как мне заменить первый символ во втором столбце ?

Comment: @May_be, в цикле перебираете все строки, находите нужную строку, меняете значение. В чем собственно проблема? Что именно не получается?

Comment: @May_be, "как мне заменить первый символ во втором столбце" - в чём проблема найти первое вхождение "_x" в строке и заменить его на "_y" ( _ - это пробел)? Более того, если у вас формат жёстко задан, то можно вообще просто заменить 5й символ в каждой строке на нужный.

Comment: @May_be, обновил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @Alekcvp я так и сделал, просто прописал типа ....=.....Insert(3," ");